# Problem updating Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, crashlytics

I am following the steps to migrate from [Fabric Crashlytic to Firebase Craslytic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) and it is giving me the following problem, I get the following error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I have **build.gradle** project  as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //mavenLocal() must be listed at the top to facilitate testing
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and **build.gradle: app** as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {

        // Add the Google Services Gradle plugin (if it's not there already).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // Add the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Apply the Google Services plugin (if it's not there already).
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts-private/internal-snapshots' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "------------"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried adding `implementation 'com.google.code.gson: gson: 2.8.5'` but I can't fix it, I've searched the internet and can't find much more information. Any suggestions to fix the problem?

Comment: I think your implementation "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'" makes this issue. Can you comment on those and check

Comment: I tried what you said @ShaluTD but the error persist. Thanks for try helping me

Comment: I am using firebase version "17.2.0" instead of 17.4.3

Comment: @ShaluTD i solved the problem as shows my answer, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try adding mavenCentral()

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

To your repositories

Answer (score 0):

After many tests I have solved the problem, in my case it has been solved by removing:

```
// Add the Google Services Gradle plugin (if it's not there already).
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
```

in the build.gradle: app dependencies in buildscript, leaving the file as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Apply the Google Services plugin (if it's not there already).
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts-private/internal-snapshots' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "------------"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```